# "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu" is giving issue when running jest test after version update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, npm-package

I am working on a react project created by create-react-app with all default settings. I am using `"react-horizontal-scrolling-menu"` package in my code and previously I was using version `"3.2.5"` and when I was running jest test, it was working fine.

Now recently I have updated its version from `3.2.5` to `4.0.4` and now when I am running npm run test, I am getting [image]

I have just updated the version by running command `npm install react-horizontal-scrolling-menu@latest`

You can reproduce the issue by

1. create a new react app
2. install latest react-horizontal-scrolling-menu
3. run command `npm run test` or `yarn run test`
4. error gets displayed